# Is a topology on a closed always a discrete topology?

Tags: general-topology

In our lecture notes, we have the following example

Let $a\in X$ and topology $T =\{G \subseteq X : a\in G \}\cup \{\varnothing\}$

It is mentioned that if $v=\{a\}$ or $v=\{a,x\}$ for some $a\neq x\in X$ then the topology on the closed set $v^c$ is the discrete topology.

1. Is this always true for any topology?
2. Also, what is meant by the topology on $v^c$? Does it mean $T\cap v^c=P(v^c)$?.

Comment: So $X$ is a topological space and $T$ the family of open sets? And what is $v$?

Comment: Is $T$ meant to be a topology? It is not because it does not contain the empty set.

Comment: @drhab, It does contain the empty set. I forgot to add it.

Comment: @Matthias, $v$ is an open set because it contains $a$.

Comment: Isn't $X=\mathbb R$ with $T$ its standard topology and $C=[0,\infty)$ a counter-example for $1.$? (I am not completely sure I understand your question). As for $2.$, I guess it means the topology induced on $v^c$ by $T$.

Comment: The induced topology on $v^c$ is $\{ U \cap v^c : U \in T \}$. So if I'm not making a stupid error in my head this seems wrong, it seems like $v^c$ has the *indiscrete* topology, because it is disjoint from every open set except $X$.

Comment: @Ian Given any set $V\subseteq X$, $V\cup v \in T$ so ..

Comment: @Ian, If  $X=\{a,b,c\}$ , then $\{a,b\}$,$v=\{ a \}$ are open sets and $v^c=\{b,c\}$ closed set. But $v^c\cap \{a,b\}\neq \phi$ so it is not disjoint from every open set.

Comment: There's the stupid mistake, thanks. So then yes, for each $b \in v^c$, the open set $\{ a,b \}$ will intersect with $v^c$ to give $\{ b \}$, so $v^c$ is discrete. This is specific to this one case. I think the right visualization of this space is that without $a$, it's a bunch of isolated points, but then you stuck $a$ to *all of them*.

Comment: Pedantic nitpick: The symbol for the empty set is not the Greek letter ϕ, it is the Norwegian letter Ø. The command is `\emptyset` $\emptyset$ or `\varnothing` $\varnothing$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring, so it is the discrete topology?

Comment: It is the discrete topology here, specifically because this space is basically a bunch of isolated points that are all indistinguishable from a single other point. So if that other point is cut out then the points are isolated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 is no, of course. In $\Bbb R$ in the usual topology, the complement of a singleton does not have the discrete topology.

If $A$ is a subset, then $\mathcal{T}_A:=\{A \cap O\mid O \in \mathcal{T}\}$ is the topology on $A$ in $(X,\mathcal{T})$.

And indeed $\mathcal{T}_A=\mathscr{P}(A)$ for $A=\{a\}^\complement$ or $A=\{x,a\}^\complement$ as is easy to see: for any subset $B$ of $A$, we have that $B \cup \{a\} \in \mathcal{T}$ and $(B \cup \{a\}\cap A = B \in \mathcal{T}_A$.